# Generating AAD Token with UPN

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to generate a token for a user with below code.

```
string apiResourceId = "11224320-66b9-4132-8953-9aa485f07004";
string clientId = "bc9869a0-2393-4e42-8c52-845071640ea8";
Uri redirectUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44335/");
string authority = string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}",
                            "rudderless.onmicrosoft.com");
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, clientId, 
            redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, null));
```

I have been getting an error in AcquireTokenAsync call -

> AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter:
>   'client_secret or client_assertion'. Trace ID:
>   a198696d-8377-40eb-8351-527a25183500 Correlation ID:
>   24d4b47d-67bf-46c0-a6b7-a248c434512e Timestamp: 2017-09-20 23:09:38Z

Why do I need a client_secret or client_assertion if I want to generate a token when a user is authenticated against a AAD? The type of Client I am using is "Web app /API". However when I am trying to use a Native client I get the token generated but API call to apResourceID is generating unauthorized error.

Few Questions I am seeking help on related to the scinario -

1. Why I need to provide client_secret when I am using user auth flow?
2. Why AcquireToken succeed when I change the client Type to Native?
3. Why the token generated through native client gives an Unauthorize error?
4. Is there a way for admin to consent on behalf of every user in AAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why I need to provide client_secret when I am using user auth flow?

Web Apps and APIs are considered **Confidential Clients**. See [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) for a definition of the different Client Types in the OAuth 2 Specification. These kinds of client always need to use their client secret to authenticate, no matter the flow they are following.

```
Confidential clients are typically issued (or establish) a set of
  client credentials used for authenticating with the authorization
  server (e.g., password, public/private key pair).
```

> 2. Why AcquireToken succeed when I change the client Type to Native?

Native Client Applications are a subset of **Public Clients**. These are defined, in the specification as:

```
Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
  credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
  resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
  browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
  authentication via any other means.
```

Therefore, they do not have or need a `client_secret` to authenticate... but this also means they can only authenticate with user context, whereas a confidential client could authenticate without a user present ([Client Credential Flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)).

> 3. Why the token generated through native client gives an Unauthorize
>    error?

This is hard to answer without knowing more about the error and the call you are making that causes this error. You should provide more information about this scenario.

> 4. Is there a way for admin to consent on behalf of every user
>    in AAD?

Yes. In the new Azure Active Directory V2 Endpoint, we have an "[Admin Consent Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)".

Using the older V1 endpoint, we have an `&prompt=admin_consent` query string which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent).